# How to concatenate date variables to create between in where condition

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, where-clause

While I am trying to set my value to between the user given start date and end date for a query, I am running into a run-time error 3071 (The expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex)

This is being used to pass a user given variable from a form to a query

Please see below

```
WHERE (
IIf([Forms]![Find]![Entity]<>"",DB.Entity=[Forms]![Find]![Entity],"*")
AND IIf([Forms]![Find]![AEPS]<>"",DB.AEPSProgram=[Forms]![Find]![AEPS],"*")
AND IIf([Forms]![Find]![DeliveryType]<>"",DB.DeliveryType=[Forms]![Find]![DeliveryType],"*")
AND IIf([Forms]![Find]![ReportingYear] is not Null,DB.ReportingYear=[Forms]![Find]![ReportingYear],"*")
AND IIf([Forms]![Find]![Price] is not Null,DB.Price=[Forms]![Find]![Price],"*")
AND IIf([Forms]![Find]![Volume]is not Null,DB.Volume=[Forms]![Find]![Volume],"*")
AND IIf([Forms]![Find]![sDate] is not Null AND [Forms]![Find]![eDate] is not Null,DB.TransactionDate= ">" & [Forms]![Find]![sdate] & " and <" & [Forms]![Find]![edate],"*")
);
```

If I set it equal to one of the dates it works as expected. I assume I am missing something with how I am joining the dates

Thank you

Comment: Please show the fuller SQL query and how this snippet is incorporated in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hello, I have added the entire where clause. The rest is quite large as I am grabbing quite a few fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (for the date field only) works:

```
WHERE (((DB.TransactionDate)>[Forms]![Find]![sdate] And (DB.TransactionDate)<[Forms]![Find]![edate])) OR ((([Forms]![Find]![sDate]+[Forms]![Find]![eDate]) Is Null));
```

Don't use *, it is for use with *Like*.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! the false condition never crossed my mind as being the problem

Answer (score 1):

Consider assigning `NULL` condition to corresponding column via `NZ()` which sets column equal to  itself and so avoids filtering any rows by that respective condition. Asterisks alone does not evaluate to a boolean condition unless using `LIKE` operator.

```
WHERE DB.Entity = NZ([Forms]![Find]![Entity], DBEntity) 
  AND DB.AEPSProgram = NZ([Forms]![Find]![AEPS], DB.AEPSProgram)
  AND DB.DeliveryType = NZ([Forms]![Find]![DeliveryType], DB.DeliveryType)
  AND DB.ReportingYear = NZ([Forms]![Find]![ReportingYear], DB.ReportingYear)
  AND DB.Price = NZ([Forms]![Find]![Price], DB.Price)
  AND DB.Volume = NZ([Forms]![Find]![Volume], DB.Volume)    
  AND DB.TransactionDate >= NZ([Forms]![Find]![sdate], DB.TransactionDate)
  AND DB.TransactionDate <= NZ([Forms]![Find]![edate], DB.TransactionDate)
;
```